# Java template interface extending problem

Tags: java, templates, extending

I want to do something like that, but the IDE tell me "Duplicate Class".

```
public class Test {
    class A1 {} class B1{} class B2{}
    interface IParent<A, B> {
        A toA(B b);
    }
    interface IChild extends 
            IParent<A1, B1>,
            IParent<A1, B2>
    {}
}
```

so I changed an uglier way, but still can not work, errorMsg: "both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other "

```
public class Test {
    class A1 {} class B1{} class B2{}
    interface IParent<A, B> {
        A toA(B b);
    }
    interface IParent1<A, B> {
        A toA(B b);
    }
    interface IChild extends
            IParent<A1, B1>,
            IParent1<A1, B2>
    {}
}
```

thanks for any help
the real thing is like

```
public class Test {
    class A1 {} class B1{} class B2{} class B3{}
    class AA1 {} class BB1{}
    interface IA1 {
        A1 toA(B1 b);
        A1 toA(B2 b);
        A1 toA(B3 b);

        boolean judge(A1 a, B1 b);
        boolean judge(A1 a, B2 b);
        boolean judge(A1 a, B3 b);
        
        A1 xx(A1 a, B1 b);
        A1 xx(A1 a, B2 b);
        A1 xx(A1 a, B3 b);
        // more method like above...
    }
    interface IAA1 {
        AA1 toA(BB1 b);
        boolean judge(AA1 a, BB1 b);
        AA1 xx(AA1 a, BB1 b);
        // more method like above...
    }
    // more class and interface like above
}
```

Comment: Yes. Because of type erasure. You can't extend/implement an interface more than 1 time, not even with different generic types, because the type variables will always be erased and become `Object`s. You can probably change the method name for the second parent to have it work.

Comment: can you explain the objective of  with the IChild ?  is this what you are trying to get ?   

`interface IChildS<A, B extends B1, C extends B2> {
    A toA(B b);
    A toA(C c);
}
`

Comment: @PrasadU I explianed in the end,